# Currency hedging 3 month sterling libor futures

Tags: portfolio-management, futures, hedging, currency, libor

Each libor contract is 500,000 gbp. Can I hedge it by going short 8 gbp/usd futures per libor to hedge out currency risk considering each gbp/usd futures is 62,500 British pounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you need to hedge the full notional? Your currency exposure is via the margin (if you post in GBP) and the PNL, neither of which are anywhere near as much as the notional.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; I would assume that the same would be for any foreign equity/fixed income trade?

Comment: Depends on whether it's funded or unfunded.

Comment: You're right. futures aren't funded unless you hit the maintenance margin requirement and you have to post it.